# How to print maximum number in a list using loop in python

Tags: python

I made a program and I might be making a conceptual error can anyone help me to figure it out?

```
l=[1,7,6,2,3]

x=0

y=0

for i in l:

    if(i>y):
        x=i
    else:
        x=y
    y=i    
print (x)
```

The output it gives is 3 i.e. the last number in the list

CAN ANYONE POINT OUT MY MISTAKE PLSS

Comment: I am not sure if you are doing this for fun or an assignment or something else but you can also use the built-in max function.

    print(max(l))

Answer (score 2):

This code will work for both positive and negative entries.

```
l=[1,7,6,2,3]

MAX = float('-inf')
for i in l:
    if(MAX < i):
        MAX = i

print(MAX)
```

Output: `7`
*You can also solve this without a for-loop.*

like this:
Code

```
l=[1,7,6,2,3]
print(max(l))
```

Output

```
7
```

Comment: You could use MAX = float('-inf'), but whole idea of this statement highly depend on Python version anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... edited my code ...Please, let me know if it is fine.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I meant... If I was you, I would revert your code to previous version... :-)

Comment: I think now its fine.

Comment: Yes, I just posted similar snipped. 1 up for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was

```
y = i
```

in line 13, you should do

```
y = x
```

instead.
However, if you do not need to use loop for some bizarre reason, the best solution would be to use max function, as others already pointed out.
If you prefer to use your function, I would optimise it even further, for example:

```
l = (-1000, 1, 7, 6, 2, 3, 1000)
x = float('-inf')
for i in l:
    if i > x:
        x = i
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

The following loop will work,

```
    l=[1,7,6,2,3]
    x=0
    for i in l:
        if(i>x):
            x=i 
    print (x)
```

You can also use the `max()` method to find the largest element in a list,

```
`max(l)` will return `7`.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[1,7,6,2,3]

max=0 # set the max of the list to 0 to start

for i in l: # run through the entire list
    if(max<i): # check to see if the present element > max
         max=i # if so, set max to that value

print (max)
```